# PHP: How to convert string to WINDOWS-1252 entities/characters?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, html-entities, windows-1252

I have the following string:

`LONDON — Britain’s unemployment rate held steady in the three months through January, reinforcing the Bank of England’s case for keeping interest rates at a record low.`

If I use something like `htmlentities` I get the following string:

`LONDON &mdash; Britain&rsquo;s unemployment rate held steady in the three months through January, reinforcing the Bank of England&rsquo;s case for keeping interest rates at a record low.`

However I want to get WINDOWS-1252 entities instead such as:

`LONDON &#151; Britain&#146;s unemployment rate held steady in the three months through January, reinforcing the Bank of England&#146;s case for keeping interest rates at a record low.`

I've tried using different functions such as `mb_convert_encoding`, `iconv`, `get_html_translation_table` but I'm unable to find a way to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the conversion is the `&#ASCII;` in format. So using the ascii value of those's special characters, you can easily implement it in `preg_replace_callback` function. Take a look at the following example:

```
$text = <<<EOT
LONDON — Britain’s unemployment rate held steady in the three months through January, reinforcing the Bank of England’s case for keeping interest rates at a record low.
EOT;

$text = preg_replace_callback(
    "/([—’])/",   // <-- place characters inside the [] if you need to change
    function ($m){ return "&#".ord($m[1]).";"; },
    $text
);

print "$text\n";
```

I have just used two(`—’`) characters here inside `[]`. if you need more, just add those one by one.

Comment: Unfortunately that seems like it added too much encoding. Wen running your code I get the following `LONDON &#226;&#128;&#148; Britain&#226;&#128;&#153;s unemployment rate held steady in the three months through January, reinforcing the Bank of England&#226;&#128;&#153;s case for keeping interest rates at a record low.`